# Buscar links(path) quebrados no projeto no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, plugin, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Tenho um projeto web no Visual Studio 2012 e gostaria de saber se existi alguma forma de varrer o código em busca de caminhos para arquivos que não estejam certos e também identificar arquivos que não são utilizados.

Por exemplo, digamos que no meu aspx eu tenha chamadas para arquivos css:

```
<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Mas digamos que na pasta css não exista o arquivo site.css, gostaria que a aplicação me informasse esse caso. E caso exista alguma arquivo css nesta mesma pasta mas não tenha referência em nenhuma parte do código gostaria de ser alertado também.

Algum plugin(extensão) para o VS ou forma nativa de se fazer isso? Alguem que já tenha utilizado o Resharper sabe dizer se ele faz esse tipo de varredura?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para verificar quais os ficheiros que não estão a ser utilizados, existe (pelo menos) esta [extensão](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28650fe9-f41e-4db9-9d61-4e3f59c85b5e).

Em relação a referências inexistentes, o Resharper tem esse tipo de verificação.

Comment: Poderia explicar como ele funciona, ou dá exemplos de como verificar isso?

Comment: @Marconi o Resharper coloca um sublinhado sob o script/stylesheet inexistente.

Comment: Show @AndréFigueiredo!! Vou testar essas extensão ai e em breve faço com o Resharper também para comparar. Agradeço a ajuda.